# Is there a bug in the Limit Clause for Zend Framework 2.2.4

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

```
$db_adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
'database' => 'xxxx',
'username' => 'xxxx',
'password' => 'xxxx',
'hostname' => 'xxxx'
    ));

$select1 = new Zend\Db\Sql\select();
$select1-> from('states');
$select1-> columns(array('name', 'id'));
$select1-> where ->notEqualTo('name', 'Florida');
$select1-> limit(5);

echo "<br />Query: ". $select1-> getSqlString() . '<br />';
$adaptor    = new Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect($select1, $db_adapter);
echo "<br />Row count: ". $adaptor->count();
```

Here is the problem:  I have a table called states that has 73 records in it. When i run the script above i keep getting 73 records, it does seem that the **LIMIT clause does not take effect at all**. I am not sure what i am doing wrong unless the limit clause is simply not working. here is the output:

```
    Query: SELECT "jb_states"."name" AS "name", 
    "jb_states"."id" AS "id" FROM "jb_states" 
    WHERE "name" != 'Florida' LIMIT '5'
    Row count: 73
```

Zend Framework version 2.2.4, database:mysql

Comment: try replacing this block $select1-> where ->notEqualTo('name', 'Florida'); with this $select1-> where($select1 ->notEqualTo('name', 'Florida'));

Answer (score 3):

`$adaptor->count()` is designed to return the **total** number of rows in the result set. It removes any limit clause before running the query in order to work this out.

Comment: Which is completely understandable because a paginator is supposed to split up a whole list into pieces - so it must know the total numbers.

Comment: Thanks Tim but Now how do I get the limit functionality then? If I pass the select1 to the paginator object it still returns everything.

Comment: i understand that pagination needs to split the entire list into pieces but my intent is to give it my own list (A subset of my table). What if the table states had 20 millions rows?  This does not quite make sense, cause i want to paginate only a subset that is why i used the LIMIT clause to begin with.

Comment: @winteck you can't limit limited query. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @winteck Create a View that is the subset of your dataset and then run the Paginator Query against the View

Comment: @Sam . Actually I am not using View nor MVC. I am using the paginator as a standalone module in my code.  What is the purpose of the Limit Clause then?  The $select1-> getSqlString()  returned the query that i want to run. I understand that the adaptor remove any limit clause , then why is it that paginator does not only return 5 records as i asked it to? If the paginator ignores my limit clause as well so what is the point of using it...

Comment: @winteck A Paginator is using "Limit" internally. So you can not limit a limit. This is basic SQL. When i said "create a VIEW" i'm not talking about a ZF2 View-Script but rather an [SQL-VIEW](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp). The paginator will return a **subset of** the **total count** of items **per page**. The amount of Items per page can be set via [paginator-configuration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.paginator.configuration.html#zend-paginator-configuration)

Comment: You might be able to do something with a sub-select as well (`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM jb_states LIMIT 5)`)

Comment: Makes perfect sense . Thanks Tim and Sam. I was getting the concept wrong, i was still thinking in terms of array adapter. Obviously THERE ARE NO REASONS TO HAVE A LIMIT CLAUSE in my dbselect query if i am going to feed the later to a paginator. The paginator will use a LIMIT itself hence there reason why it dropped my own LIMIT clause. I think we can close this ticket now. Thanks for the help everyone...